# How to nested GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: android, sqlite, nested, concatenation

I have this table:

[image]

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mytable.gloss) AS gloss
...
GROUP BY mytable.entry
```

returns:

[image]

How to get result in this way-grouped by entry and sense and divided by semicolon ';' sign?'
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, group by `sense`:

```
SELECT entry,
       sense,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gloss)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY entry,
         sense

entry sense gloss
----- ----- ------------
1     1     Orange,Red
1     2     Blue
2     3     Green
2     4     Yellow,Ivory
3     5     Grey
```

Then run another `GROUP BY` on that result:

```
SELECT entry,
       MIN(sense) AS sense,
       GROUP_CONCAT(gloss, ';') AS gloss
FROM (SELECT entry,
             sense,
             GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gloss) AS gloss
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY entry,
               sense)
GROUP BY entry

entry sense gloss
----- ----- ------------------
1     1     Orange,Red;Blue
2     3     Green;Yellow,Ivory
3     5     Grey
```